# How to split a div to the left and the remaining divs to the right?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, grid

I am trying to separate the divs on the page with the help of a bootstrap grid. But despite my long efforts, I could not achieve the desired result. The result I am aiming for is as follows:

[Result on biggest screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFPND.png)

[Result on smaller screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZF0J.png)

[Result on smallest screen (the div on left doesn't get displayed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehj0S.png)

Code in ***_Layout.html*** file:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
```

```
<h4 class="text-center mt-3 mb-2">Onze shirts:</h4>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <article class="border border-info mh-100 .d-none .d-md-block col-xl-3 col-lg-1 col-md-1 ml-2">Hier komt de reclame te staan</article>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    @foreach (Models.Product product in Model.producten)
    {
        <div class="justify-content-center border border-info text-center col-10 col-xl-3 col-sm-5 col-md-5 mb-3 mt-3 ml-2" style="width:20%">
        <p><img src='Images\@product.Afbeelding' height="75" width="60" /></p>
        <p>@product.Naam</p>
        @if (product.Aanbieding != 0)
        {
            <p>van: <del>€@product.Prijs</del>  voor: €@product.Aanbieding</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>voor: €@product.Prijs</p>
        }
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="~/Bestel?artikelnummer=@product.Id">bestel</a></p>
        </div>
    }
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to separate the divs on the page with the help of a bootstrap grid.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 breakpoints: xs, sm, md, lg and xl. When you use a class `col-sm-4`, it means it will get 4/12 of the full width in sm, md, lg and xl width. So, breakpoints in classes means itself and up. Looks like you used `sm`, `md` and `lg` classes. If you want the layout be same in all screen sizes, just use `xs` classes or completely omit the breakpoints like `col-2`, `col-4`.